# What should I do when I created a bounty on my own question and answered it myself?

Tags: support

Ok so I've added a bounty to my own question and after a while I managed to fix it by myself.

Here's the question: [Magento 1: unable to sort grid by custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98044/magento-1-unable-to-sort-grid-by-custom-attribute)

Problem is Stackexchange tells me to assign the bounty to someone but the only answer different than mine is totally not helpful, has got negative score and it looks like the poster didn't read my question in details.

So I'm not sure about the action I should take in that case.

Comment: There are pages and pages of this question across the SE network. Did you try Googling this first?

Comment: Tbh, no I trusted the similar question suggestions and thought it would also like other meta network that's why I asked.

Comment: Ok. The search would only cover this meta, but in general I see no benefit in asking the same question on multiple site metas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't get an answer that at least pointed you in the right direction, you should not award the bounty.
In this case, and since you cannot award the bounty to yourself, the bounty points are lost forever.

Comment: I'm fine with bounty points being "lost", but I find it annoying that when I land on my profile, I see a little 1 next to bounty. No way I can get rid of it apart from deleting the question (which would be dumb as what I've found is kinda interesting) ?

Comment: That 1 will go away tomorrow.

Comment: Ok great thanks for enlighting me